Metaplex mint with metadata error
this my package.json
{
"name": "sol-final",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
"@metaplex-foundation/js": "^0.18.3",
"@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^3.2.1",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi": "^0.9.2",
"@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults": "^0.9.2",
"@metaplex/js": "^4.12.0",
"@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
"@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile": "^2.1.3",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.6",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.4",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.21",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.5",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-walletconnect": "^0.1.16",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.16.0",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.36.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.8.0",
"axios": "^1.7.2",
"bs58": "^6.0.0",
"buffer": "6.0.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"tweetnacl": "^1.0.3",
"tweetnacl-util": "^0.15.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "set HTTPS=true && set SSL_CRT_FILE=localhost.pem && set SSL_KEY_FILE=localhost-key.pem&&react-app-rewired start",
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
]
},
"devDependencies": {
"ajv": "^7.2.4",
"assert": "^2.1.0",
"browser": "^0.2.6",
"browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
"buffer": "^6.0.3",
"crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
"https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
"os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
"path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
"process": "^0.11.10",
"react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
"source-map-loader": "^5.0.0",
"stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
"stream-http": "^3.2.0",
"url": "^0.11.3",
"webpack": "^5.91.0"
}
}
i have followed the docs
https://developers.metaplex.com/core/create-asset
const MintNFT = async () => {
    const umi = createUmi('https://rpc.ankr.com/solana_devnet').use(mplCore())
    const assetSigner = generateSigner(umi)
    const result = createV1(umi, {
        asset: assetSigner,
        name: 'My Nft',
        uri: 'https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmVwuwM8Swemify5YZ48BeLr1ffv6WF5GGPAgjTyfceceL/necklacpawnticket_zxczx_10.txt',
      }).sendAndConfirm(umi)
};

i have done this i am facing error
tokenGroup.ts:5 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , codecs_1.getBytesCodec) is not a function
at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-group/lib/cjs/state/tokenGroup.js (tokenGroup.ts:5:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-group/lib/cjs/state/index.js (index.ts:1:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:22:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-group/lib/cjs/index.js (index.ts:3:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

This question is similar to: Error in @metaplex-foundation/js. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
